# C# Creating white space lines between assembled .text

Tags: c#

```
 private void btnAssemble_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtAssembled.Text = (cboTitle.Text +  txtFirstName.Text[0] + txtMiddle.Text + txtLastName.Text + "\r\n" +txtStreet.Text + "\r\n"+ cboCity.Text);           
    }
```

I'm trying to get 1 character white space inbetween cboTitle.Text, txtFirname.Text, txtMiddle.Text, and txtLastName, but they all output the information together, but I want them spaced evenly. what do I need to do? thanks in advance.

I'm going to post some other code thats below the one above in my project, just in case it might be relevant.

```
 string AssembleText(string Title, string FirstName, string MiddleInitial, string LastName, string AddressLines, string City )
    {
        string Result = "";
        Result += Title + " ";
        Result += FirstName.Substring(0, 2) + " ";

        // Only append middle initial if it is entered
        if (MiddleInitial != "")
        {
            Result += MiddleInitial + " ";
        }

        Result += LastName + "\r\n";

        // Only append items from the multiline address box
        // if they are entered
        if ( AddressLines != "")
        {
            Result += AddressLines + "\r\n";
        }
        //if (AddressLines.Length > 0 && AddressLines.ToString() != "")
        //{
        //    Result += AddressLines + "\r\n";
        //}


        Result += City;

        return Result;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean like this: `cboTitle.Text + " "  + txtFirstName.Text[0] + " " + txtMiddle.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text`?

Comment: Cheers thats the one thank you!

Comment: "I want them spaced evenly" - What do you mean by this? Do you just want a space or newline between the values, or something else?

Comment: First, if you are concatenating these many strings use either `String.Format()` or `StringBuilder`. Second I would suggest that you add whites spaces everywhere required just as @mrahhal showed in the above comment and then use regex to ensure that you don't get multiple white spaces. 
If you could provide with a sample expected output it would be helpful in providing a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a space between those specific fields in btnAssemble_Click, you can just insert them like this:

`string myStr = foo + " " + bar + " " + baz;`

So your first function would be modified to read:

`private void btnAssemble_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtAssembled.Text = (cboTitle.Text + " " + txtFirstName.Text[0] + " " + txtMiddle.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text + "\r\n" + txtStreet.Text + "\r\n" + cboCity.Text);
}`

A few other comments:

- It's not clear to me what the AssembleText() function you posted has to do with this. I am confused though, as I see a few lines appending spaces at the end just like I mentioned above.
- Using the String.Format() function may make this code easier to read and maintain.
- Using Environment.NewLine instead of "\r\n" will make the string contain the newline character defined for that specific environment.
- Using a StringBuilder object may be faster over concatenation when building strings inside of a loop (which may not apply here).

Answer (score 1):

Using String.format() should feet the bill. It also make your code easy to read.

```
txt.assembled.text = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}",
cboTitle.Text,
txtFirstName.Text[0],
txtMiddle.Text,
txtLastName.Text
);
```

Comment: Consider string interpolation instead in C#6: `$"{cboTitle.Text} {txtFirstName.Text[0]} {txtMiddle.Text} {txtLastName.Text}"`

Answer (score 1):

It would be like this

```
 private void btnAssemble_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtAssembled.Text = (cboTitle.Text + " " + txtFirstName.Text[0] + " " +txtMiddle.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text + "\r\n" +txtStreet.Text + "\r\n"+ cboCity.Text);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want `String.Join`; whenever you want to combine strings with a delimiter, say, `" "` (space) all you need is to put

```
  String combined = String.Join(" ", 
                                cboTitle.Text, 
                                txtFirstName.Text[0], 
                                txtMiddle.Text, 
                                txtLastName.Text);
```

Complete implementation (joining by *space* and *new line*) could be

```
  txtAssembled.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    String.Join(" ", 
                cboTitle.Text, 
                txtFirstName.Text[0], 
                txtMiddle.Text, 
                txtLastName.Text),
    txtStreet.Text, 
    cboCity.Text);
```